# Show Many to many field images in the admin page next to the field itself

Tags: python, django

First of all, after you read this question, feel free to suggest edits for the title cause I'm not sure what to type

I have this hierarchy..
`Stone` -> `Subtype` -> `Subtype` -> `Subtype` and this goes as long as the `Stone` has a `Subtype` in real life. So it's not known how many times will I add `Subtypes` to a specific stone. Let's inspect it

```
# models.py

from django.db import models
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

class Stone(models.Model):
    name = ...
    sub_type = models.ForeignKey('StoneSubType', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING ,related_name='stones', blank=True, null=True)



class StoneSubType(models.Model):
    name = ...
    sub_type = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='sub_types', blank=True)


class StoneSubtypeImage(models.Model):
    stone = models.ForeignKey('StoneSubType', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='images')
    image = models.ImageField(default=None, upload_to='stone_subtypes/')



class StoneImage(models.Model):
    stone = models.ForeignKey('Stone', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='images')
    image = models.ImageField(default=None, upload_to='stones/')

    def image_tag(self):
        return mark_safe(f'<img src="{self.image.url}">')
```

Let's go the admin page to illustrate what I want

[image]

Now, Every `Subtype` has some images, and the `Stone` itself has some images of course, Images are as shown in the code, So I made them appear in the admin page as an `Inline` which is shown there when I scroll down. Like this

[image]

Now, I want to show the image(s) of the `Subtype` next to the `Subtype` field. Any suggestions on how can we do this?

My limit was at showing the Inline images in the same page. 
Search results think I want that, But it's not that

I found a work around for now. But it doesn't insert the images next to their field.

This is the Subtype model manager

```
class StoneSubtypeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [StoneSubtypeImagesInline]
    search_fields = ['name', 'category', 'price', 'color__name',]
    filter_horizontal = ['sub_type']

    fields = ['name', 'sub_type', 'sub_type_images', 'category', 'block_num', 'salab_num', 'barcode', 'commercial_size', 'price', 'details', 'town', 'country', 'color', 'surface' ]
    readonly_fields = ['sub_type_images']

    def sub_type_images(self, obj):
        if obj.sub_type is not None:
            output = ''  # html here

            for sub_type in obj.sub_type.all():
                for image in sub_type.images.all():
                    output += (
                        f'<div class="column">'
                        f'<h3 class="heading"> {obj.name} </h3>'
                        f'<a href="/admin/core/stonesubtype/{sub_type.pk}/"><img src="{image.image.url}" style="max-height: 300px"></a>'
                        f'</div>'
                    )
            output = f'<div class="image_grid"> {output}</div> <style> .image_grid {{display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 250px); grid-template-rows: auto auto auto; .heading {{ font-size: 20p !important; display: inline-block; }} .column {{ display: flex; flex-direction: column }} </style>'
            return mark_safe(output)
```

and it shows the images now below the `Subtype` as a separate field. The solution is getting nearer.

Comment: So you want the images to appear next to the sub type select lists where they can choose multiple subtypes? Could you add a mock up image demonstrating your desired output to help us visualise that please

Comment: Yes exactly, I will do this and edit the question.

Comment: I edited, Images of the Subtype and not just one image 
they should appear after I select the Subtype i.e move it to the right

Comment: I've been trying since asking, I reached something, I got them to display (not in the right place tho) and now I'll update the code